What is the general rule for combining smaller hardware multipliers to create a larger multiplier?
FPGAs have DSP blocks that are hard multipliers. These have a fixed upper size for operands e.g 9 bit each or 18 bit each e.t.c. The actual size depends on the vendor and FPGA family.
Now I know that it is possible to combine smaller multipliers to create a larger multiplier. However, what is not clear is the general rule. e.g how to create 32x32 bit multiplier when we only have 9x9 bit or 18x18 bit multipliers?
So the question is, what is the general rule when creating mxm bit multiplier from nxn bit DSP blocks here m < n.

The general rule is let the tools do it for you. Just write the required generic multiplication using your HDL's syntax, and the vendor tools will synthesize the correct mix of DSP blocks and logic to get the job done.

I know that, but I still need to know how its done so I have an idea of how much logic it will use.

I saw in Quartus that to create 32x32 bit multiplier, we need 8 of 9x9 bit multiplier, we need 4 of 18x18 bit multipliers. Similarly, to create 64x64 multiplier, we need 30 of 9x9 bit multiplier and 15 of 18x18 bit multiplier. Then, there is there also all the logic for the sum of the partial products. That would create a massive propagation delay.

Yes, if you want high throughput, you add some number of pipeline registers to the multiplier. The synthesis tools are generally smart enough to migrate those registers into the DSP pipeline in order to balance the delays and give you the highest possible clock rate. If you need tighter control over the process, the vendors have "wizards" that allow you to explicitly specify details like that.

Yes, but is it still worth knowing what amount or type of logic it could consume. I was shocked when I saw that 64x64 multiplier would need 30 of 9x9 multipliers. That is quite a lot of multipliers!

But not really surprising if you think about it. If you can afford to spend multiple clock cycles on each multiply operation, you can multiply-accumulate partial products with a much smaller physical multiplier. I don't know how much the wizards can help with that.

@gyuunyuu 30 is actually very good! A naive approach would have needed at least 50 multipliers. So, that already proves that you're dealing with hardware-optimized ways to combine multipliers.

As discussed in the comments, you will need to use the tools of the vendor to get exact results, because DSP slices are designed for these kinds of combined operations, and the general approach doesn't hold for them exactly. So, no matter how you toss and turn, I'm sorry, your "but I want to compute the resource needs independently from the exact nature of the resources" is doomed.
Anyways, assume this: you want to build an iterative multiplier. You have a single DSP slice, and you want to use it repeatedly until you get the final results. How many iterations will you need to multiply two \$k\cdot N\$ long variables, using a \$\mathbb F^N\times\mathbb F^N\mapsto \mathbb F^{2N}\$ multiplier?
(Ignoring the combinational depth issue, this gives you an answer for how many multipliers you'd need if you want to do it in a single iteration.)
The answer is simple: the complexity of long multiplication, quadratic to \$k\$. Instead of thinking in decimal or in binary, imagine you think in a base-\$2^N\$ numbers; that means each digit has \$N\$ bits. Then, you're doing a \$k\$-digit long multiplication: That takes \$k\$ elementary products (with carry-over) for each of the \$k\$ digits of the first factor, and a final sum.
So, your naive larger-than-DSP-slice multiplier could, proper scheduling of the partial sums involved, do in \$k^2\$ iterations.
Of course, if you look closer, you can do things like Karatsuba's algorithm, which reduces the exponent of \$2\$ to a much nicer \$\log_2 3\$, but you need hardware support in your elementary multipliers for that! Toom-Cook is an abstraction, if you will, of that idea, combined with the fact that you can do elegant things if you choose to "split" your overall multiplication into prime dividers of the original length. If you can build the logic around that, you can do, for \$k\mod 3 \equiv 0\$, a \$k\cdot N\$ multiplication by doing \$5\$ multiplications of length \$\frac k3  \cdot N\$ (and that's much better than our simple "how can I combine theoretical combiners" result).
So, all the these nice "How do I combine multipliers into larger multipliers" theory results extremely hinge on how your multipliers work and what outputs they are able to give you. Will you need in the order of  \$k^2\$ or \$k^{\log_2 3}\$ or \$k^{\log 5 / \log 3}\$ individual "smaller" multiplications? And, compared to the usage in resources of multipliers, how is the wiring/routing effort, both in terms of FPGA routing grid resources as well as power? What does really make the most sense for a given FPGA architecture? Does this still run at the clock rate and latency you need it to run, or is using more DSP slices than strictly necessary to achieve a higher clock rate necessary?
The DSP slices on FPGAs are arranged in ways that allow them to be connected, including their carry-over bits, so that they can be used as larger units. Some are splittable into smaller multipliers, and so on. The designers of these multiplier units, and of the FPGA as a whole, had trade-offs in mind while they designed and placed those things, and that means that, yes, you will need to look at the individual FPGA you're dealing with even when you just want to know roughly how much resources you'll need.
For large factor lengths, you'd do things differently altogether, and not combine your large product from smaller products with carry-over at all; there's elegant \$\mathcal O\left(n\cdot\log n\cdot \log\log n\right)\$ (\$n=k\cdot N\$) algorithms, based on ideas that FFTs also employ. But what that actually means in resource consumption compared to any of the previously mentioned approaches: impossible to tell, again, without considering the actual device. (hey, if you're multiplying large numbers, you might need to store them and intermediate results in BRAM anyways, so you need to take the availability, placement, and speed of these into account as well.)
So, honestly, I don't really know what the fuzz here is about: If you just need to write a "worst case sensible number" down for comparison purposes, go with \$k^2\$ (and I bet you already figured that one out…), and if you need anything more precise, you need to actually implement the multiplier and read the synthesis report.

I am creating a design that should be possible to implement across various vendor FPGAs. This is one of the things that I need to have an idea about since some FPGAs have 9x9 multipliers and others have larger sizes.

exactly, so you need different synthesis reports
